# Java library not being added to run time dependencies in Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, runtime, shared-libraries

Using IDEA, I am trying to use a library jar that I put in my project/libs folder. It works at compile time, but at run time it doesnt show up.

I've used IDEA to add the library jar to both my modules and library under project structure.

[image: IDEA pls help]

I even have a build.gradle in there somewhere that is just. I didnt provide a artifactid nor a groupid.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

The actual error that is being thrown is a NoClassDefFoundError exception when I use a method that works during compile time, but not at run time because it doesn't bring the library to the output folder.

EDIT: Dependencies and stack trace
[image: uhh why]

Comment: Try refreshing gradle from  `Views → Tool Windows → Gradle` . And also try restarting intellij after that.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your module dependencies and also a complete stacktrace of the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried restarting Intellij and Gradle builds, but I dont think I made the gradle properly. I also added a picture of dependencies w/ stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`.